# Cocoa - Send email

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [send email through a cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619731/send-email-through-a-cocoa-application)
>   [Send Email - Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396229/send-email-cocoa)

How can I send email in cocoa/objective-C? I've seen ways that open up mail.app and send it but I want it to run in the background. External frameworks are ok but not preferred.

-Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send Email - Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396229/send-email-cocoa) and [send email through a cocoa application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619731/send-email-through-a-cocoa-application)