# Sending email programmatically with Mac

Tags: macos, email, automation

My Mac has Lion OS X 10.7.4 and Xcode 4.3.2.

I'd like to be able to send emails programmatically (i.e. without human intervention).  What is the recommended approach with these (latest) environments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things [about the EDMessage framework](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/EDFrameworks/).

You could also possibly use Applescript or Python too.  [Peter Hosey posted about this in his answer to this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619731/send-email-through-a-cocoa-application).

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I'll explore these.